# Auditing SSH sessions?

Tags: linux, ssh, audit

I'm looking for a way that I can record and audit SSH sessions for users on my server. I need to be able to know when a user executed a command, what command they executed, and also be able to follow them through logins into other accounts (if a user were to run `sudo -Hiu otheruser`, the `otheruser` session should still be tracked from the main user's logs since they did not log in directly).

`script` doesn't seem to be a solution since the logs are recorded from the user's account which makes it vulnerable to tampering/destruction, and it also doesn't have timestamps for the commands.

Is there a commonly used tool / open source suite for a use case like this?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to have been asked, and answered, many times before:
[Stack Exchange to the Rescue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25639/how-to-automatically-record-all-your-terminal-sessions-with-script-utility)

The second answer in particular seems to offer a potential solution using functionality built into SSHd itself as documented here [SSH Recording](https://jms1.net/ssh-record.shtml) but won't stand up to any determined effort to defeat it.

This technique in conjunction with the logger command may meet your requirements.

Comment: Wait, where is the bit where session recording is built into sshd itself? The page you linked to describes a really hacky way of recording sessions that is quite easy to bypass, that I can't imagine anyone describing as "elegant". What did I miss here?

Comment: I may have overstepped by calling it 'elegant', I was quite astounded to learn that SSH supports adding a command before a ssh key within the authorized keys file:

Add the forced command to each user's key: ```command="/usr/local/sbin/log-session" ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAAEBAMKr1HxJzOWRQCm16Sf...```

Comment: The problem is that the user can just remove that themselves, or add a new key that doesn't have a command in it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton agreed, I didn't assume ill intent on the part of the users, which the OP did hint at in the question.  

In a scenario where there is ill intent I doubt there is a solution that exists in userland.  

My intent in answering this question was to point out that this was a well worn path.  Then I spotted the authorized keys feature, which I could have put to use many many times and was eager to share.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 8 has [integrated session recording](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/recording_sessions/index) with the `tlog` package. For other distributions you could probably install it yourself.